# How to remove default ScrollBar from ListView in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I've been using flutter for a very long time, but in recent updates, I've observed that Default `ScrollBar` have been added to `ListView` and some other widgets also.

Does anyone know how can I remove this default `ScrollBar`?

[image]

Comment: which platform is it? Is it in Windows / web ?

Comment: It's web @ejabu

Answer (score 0):

By altering the physics property should do it

```
ListView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: <Widget>[
        //your widget items here
    ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks Jaison for answering, but I want to scroll that `ListView`